# CSS only solution to make a word appear naturally within sentence

Tags: html, css, sass, slim-lang

So I have an html.slim sentence that looks like this:

```
 p 
  | Log in to 
  span.word-shapeshift.text-center
    span.word Explore
    span.word Engage
    span.word Conquer
    span.word Defeat 
  | the members of the outer realm
```

I'm trying to make it so those words appear naturally within the sentence like so:

"Log in to **Conquer** the members of the outer realm". However, my CSS code makes it so the word appears behind the sentence. CSS code below:

```
$speed: 12s;
$wordCount: 4;

.word-shapeshift {
  color: #ecf0f1;  
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  filter: contrast(25) blur(1px);

  .word {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    animation: rotateWord $speed infinite ease-in-out;
  
    @for $i from 0 to $wordCount {
      &:nth-child(#{$i + 1}) {
        animation-delay: ($speed / ($wordCount + 1) * $i) - $speed;
      }
    }
  
    @keyframes rotateWord {
      0%, 5%, 100% { filter: blur(0px); opacity: 1; }        
      20%, 80% { filter: blur(1em); opacity: 0; }        
    }
  }
  
  
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your ‘CSS’ code does not compile cleanly either with SCSS or with SASS, which means I am unable to reproduce what you are seeing. If you edit your question to post code which compiles cleanly, happy to help.

Comment: Position absolute means the word, and therefore the span it’s contained in, does not affect the positioning of subsequent words. Does ‘naturally’ in your description mean you want the sentence to gradually grow and shrink in size with the different words or is that rotating word bit to have a constant width?

Comment: @AHaworth I wouldn't mind if the sentence shrunk/grew according to the word, since that would be more natural. At first, I considered a set space (based on largest word length), but that would look strange for the smaller words having extra spacing

Comment: OK, I have deleted my answer which reserved space relative to the longest word.

Comment: @AHaworth I mean, that was a big improvement with how it looks. The one issue being longest word in the bunch is expanding/touching up against the next word in sentence. Looking like: "Explorethe". I'll keep playing with it...

Comment: This (Explorethe) doesn't happen for me when I run the snippet. I'm on Edge/Windows10. What OS/browser are you using? Also are you setting a different font in real life?

Answer (score 0):

This snippet has 'translated' the given code into pure CSS/HTML as I found that easier to see what was going on.

To reserve enough space for the words in the sentence, the longest word (in terms of space needed) is put at the end of the sequence. The other rotating words remain position: absolute, but this 4th one has position relative so it reserves space.

Note: the color being set to #fff makes it disappear in this simple example so color settings have been removed. As color/filter/blur were not part of the problem in the question I haven't altered them further. Ditto the timing, though the timing given results in a small gap when no word shows. This can of course be altered by looking at the animation/keyframe settings.

```css
.word-shapeshift {
  /*color: #ecf0f1;*/
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  /*color: #fff;*/
  filter: contrast(25) blur(1px);
  --speed: 12s;
  --wordCount: 4;
  width: fit-content;
  display: inline-block;
  .word {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    animation: rotateWord var(--speed) infinite ease-in-out;
    animation-delay: calc(var(--speed) / (var(--wordCount) + 1) * var(--n) - var(--speed));
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    &:nth-child(1) {
      --n: 1;
    }
    &:nth-child(2) {
      --n: 2;
    }
    &:nth-child(3) {
      --n: 3;
    }
    &:nth-child(4) {
      --n: 4;
      position: relative;
    }
  }
}

@keyframes rotateWord {
  0%,
  5%,
  100% {
    filter: blur(0px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    filter: blur(1em);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Log in to <span class="word-shapeshift">
    <span class="word">Explore</span>
  <span class="word">Engage</span>
  <span class="word">Defeat</span>
  <span class="word">Conquer</span></span> the members of the outer realm</div>
```